# Disable selection for white space in HTML

Tags: html, select

I need to identify clicked word (onclick on any word in the screen I should detect that word) I'm able to get it using jQuery. I want to exclude clicking for white space.

[image]

i.e in the above, when I click anywhere between word "together" and down arrow its selecting word together but my requirement is nothing to be selected in this scenario.

I'm using https://github.com/megahertz/jquery.get-word-by-event library for word tapping.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CSS` you can disable the text select in the `html` document. So which text you want, not to be selected keep it in the `div`-tag and then implement the below `CSS` `style` object to the `div`-tag:

```
div{
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

*Hope this solves your problem.*

**Additional Changes with respect to below comment**:

```
body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }
```

Implementing this `css` on body disables all the text or any other `HTML` `object` from being selected.

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
my div width is 100% and text with in div didn't occupy 100%. when i click in remaining space (i.e beyond)text, it selecting last word in that div. But how i need is text tapping for above scenario shouldn't happen

Comment: then you need to do is implement this css on the body instead of div. I will change/update my answer accordingly. You try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following after clicking. As in after clicking pass the work through the following

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}
```

You can easily find out whether the selection is blank or has words. This would return if the white space is only selected else false.